# trying to nest foreach loop to remove items and create new array in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, nested-loops

So, I've managed to thoroughly confuse myself and any help would be greatly appreciated.
What I'm trying to do is filter out items that are restricted by a user’s country (done in my controller).

My first query gets all items (posters in this case). My second item gets the restricted posters.  This code works as planned.

I then try to create a nested loop to filter out the restricted posters from all posters by creating a new array and pushing the items that pass my if clause into my $unrestrictedPosters array. My if clause is where my code fails as I'm unable to properly access the key value in order to fulfil my if clause.

Btw, once I return $unrestrictedPosters that would then be use and looped through in my bade file.

controller code below

```
class PosterRestrictionController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $profile = app('App\Http\Controllers\DevelopmentController')->getActiveUser(Auth::id());
        $userCountry = $profile->country;
        $unrestrictedPosters = [];

        $allPosters = DB::table('posters')
        ->join('profiles', 'posters.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->join('users', 'posters.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('users.name',
                'profiles.surname',
                'profiles.country',
                'posters.id as poster_id',
                'posters.user_id',
                'posters.title',
                'posters.category',
            )
        ->orderBy('posters.id', 'asc')
        ->get();

        $restrictedPosters = DB::table('posters')
        ->join('poster_restrictions', 'poster_restrictions.poster_id', '=', 'posters.id')
        ->where('poster_restrictions.restricted_country_id', '=', $userCountry)
        ->select(
                'posters.id as poster_id',
                'poster_restrictions.poster_viewable',
                'poster_restrictions.restricted_country_id'
                )
        ->orderBy('posters.id', 'asc')
        ->get();

        

        foreach ($allPosters as $poster) {
            
            foreach ($restrictedPosters as $restrictedPoster) {

                    if ($restrictedPoster['poster_viewable'] != 0) {
                        
                        array_push($unrestrictedPosters, $poster);
                  
                }

            }
            
        }

        dd($unrestrictedPosters);
        //return $unrestrictedPosters;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you dd($restrictedPoster), what is the output ?

Comment: I do get an array item {#470 ▼
  +"poster_id": 1
  +"poster_viewable": "0"
  +"restricted_country_id": "United Kingdom"
}

Comment: `I'm unable to properly access the key value in order to fulfil my if clause.`?? you didnt getting the key to check am i right?

Comment: yes, if I dd after my second for each I get an array item but when i get to the if clause `if($restrictedPoster['poster_viewable'] )`  I get a" Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: actually, it looks like I'm gettting objects not an array. How?

Comment: Try `if( $restrictedPoster->poster_viewable != 0 )`

Comment: Yes, this seems to work and clears the error. Thank you! Can I mark cmments as answers?  As aside though, my logic seems to fail. Can you spare a few moments on this, no worries if not since it was not my original question. Basically I only have two restricted posters, 29 total posters. != 0 returns an empy array and ==0 returns 58 items (29x2).  Any ideas on the cause?

Comment: @Newbie Check a better solution in my answer, will save you a query and a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother loopingit when you can restrict them in the query

```
class PosterRestrictionController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $profile = app('App\Http\Controllers\DevelopmentController')->getActiveUser(Auth::id());
        $userCountry = $profile->country;

        $unrestrictedPosters = DB::table('posters')
        ->join('profiles', 'posters.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->join('users', 'posters.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('poster_restrictions', function($join) use($userCountry) {
            $join->on('poster_restrictions.poster_id', '=', 'posters.id')
                ->where('poster_restrictions.restricted_country_id', '=', $userCountry);
        })
        ->whereNull('poster_restrictions.restricted_country_id')

        ->select('users.name',
                'profiles.surname',
                'profiles.country',
                'posters.id as poster_id',
                'posters.user_id',
                'posters.title',
                'posters.category',
            )
        ->orderBy('posters.id', 'asc')
        ->get();

        dd($unrestrictedPosters);
        //return $unrestrictedPosters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This was my initial thought but when doing my leftJoin I was only returning the posters that were restricted so I gave up and went down the for loop path. I never thought about trying to add a function on the leftJoin. Thank you again and to everyone that commented to help.